# In NCAlgebra, how can we make d**d**d=0 if d**d=0 is given?

Tags: ncalgebra

I wrote the following code to eliminate $d^n$ from the equation for $n>1$.

```
In[1]:= m = {{A, d}, {a, -d}};
SetCommutative[a, A, d]
mm = Simplify[MatrixPower[m, 5]];
SNC[d]
d ** d = 0;
mm = Simplify[mm];
mm
```

The output I got is

```
Out[7]:= {{A^5 + 4 a A^3 d - a (2 a + d) d ** d ** d, A^4 d}, {a A^2 (A^2 + 3 a d - A d), d (a A^3 - 4 a d ** d ** d - d ** d ** d ** d)}}
```

So, it didn't make `d**d**d=0`. How to do that?
See, Actually, I am looking for a solution for `[MatrixPower[m, n]`.

Comment: I think the behaviour is expected as stated in the Property & Relations section of the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html?q=NonCommutativeMultiply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `d**d = 0` will not work. what you need is something like

```
rule = {___ ** d ** d ** ___ -> 0};
{a, a ** d, 0, 0} == NestList[# ** d &, a, 3] /. rule
```

which returns `True` as is expected. I also tried the code:

```
m = {{A, d}, {a, -d}};
mm = MatrixPower[m, 5] // Expand;
mm /. {d^n_ :> 0 /; n > 1} // InputForm
```

which returns

```
{{A^5 + 4*a*A^3*d, A^4*d}, {a*A^4 + 3*a^2*A^2*d - a*A^3*d, a*A^3*d}}
```

and this may be what you actually wanted.

Comment: In v13.0, I can't get the result {{A^5 + 4*a*A^3*d, A^4*d}, {a*A^4 + 3*a^2*A^2*d - a*A^3*d, a*A^3*d}}. But {{2 a A^3 d + A (A^2 + a d) ** (A^2 + a d) - 2 a ** a d ** d ** d, A^4 d}, {-a A^3 d + A^2 d a ** a + a (A^2 + a d) ** (A^2 + a d) + 
   2 a ** a d ** d ** d, a A^3 d}}.

Comment: @lotus2019 Thanks for that comment! Nice catch! I should have used `:>` instead of `->`.  Will fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I still can't get the result in your answer. (MMA v 13.0,  NCAlgebra - V 5.0.6) I can get the result in Mauricio de Oliveira's answer.

Comment: @lotus2019 I used MMA v 13.1 with a new kernel and got exactly the results in my answer. I did **not** use NCAlgebra. If you got different results, I suggest you upgrade to 13.1 or perhaps contact Wolfram Support.

Comment: Sorry, I used NCAlgebra. Now I can get the result in your answer without NCAlgebra. Thank you! But now I can't get True when I ran your first code without NCAlgebra. What I get is {a, a d, 0, 0} == {a, a d, a d^2, a d^3}.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as pointed out by @somos, is that `d**d=0` is not able to match *inside* more complex expressions. In `NCAlgebra` you can use `NCReplaceAll` and related functions to perform substitutions that do take into account such cases. For example:

```
SetCommutative[a, A, d]
SNC[d]
m = {{A, d}, {a, -d}};
mm = Simplify[MatrixPower[m, 5]];
```

followed by

```
NCReplaceAll[NCExpand[mm], d ** d -> 0]
```

will result in

```
{{A^5 + 4 a A^3 d, A^4 d}, {a A^4 + 3 a^2 A^2 d - a A^3 d, a A^3 d}}
```

which is what you would expect.